# Python regex match a line that doesn't contain a string

Tags: python, regex, text

I have this regex to match this pattern:

```
] 1 words 2 words
```

But I want to exclude a case, where those words contain the string "**da cui**", such as:

```
] 1 words 2 words da cui words
```

This is my regex:

```
\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+)
```

But I don't know how to insert the "exclusion" that, looking on the internet, seems:

```
^((?!da\scui).)*$
```

I don't know if it's right and where to place it.

Comment: Should the `\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+)` pattern must match the whole string? Do you mean you use it as `^\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+)$`?

Comment: No, "cui" is not the last word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?!.*da cui)\]\s+1\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+2\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/L6I8kU/1/